# I tried to clear entity manager after commit in JPA, so i am getting exceptions

Tags: java, jpa

I am using following codes.

```
e.getTransaction().commit();
e.clear();
```

but I am getting following exceptions:

> org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
>   Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Could not commit with auto-commit set on

Could you please help on this error?

Comment: what database? Mysql with autocommit?

Comment: Could you please post the complete implementation of the method? Has a transaction begun (`begin()` method call)?

Comment: The error comes from which line ... "commit" or "em.clear" ?

Comment: It might be you forgot to call `e.getTransaction().begin();` before commit()...

Comment: I am using oracle 11g db. I have already used e.getTransanction ().begin (); before commit. Code is working without e.clear (); but when i tried to clear em then i am getting exception at line e.clear ();